# Deprecate public usage of service

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.4

In a bigger application I have many services. Using Symfony 2.x we have most services public and used in the controllers:

```
$container->get('service.id');
```

Transistioning to Symfony 3.4/4 I'd like to deprecate public usage of services. Since many customers use the service directly, I have to keep them public.

But I'd like to mark the public usage of the service "deprecated".

I already know how to deprecate service definitions in Symfony (http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-deprecated-service-definitions).

Am I able to **deprecate public usage only** somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a "wanna-be-private" service by setting the `private` attribute to `true` on the service definition.

yaml: `public: true, private: true`
php: `$definition->setPublic(true)->setPrivate(true);`

That will trigger a deprecation notice when getting the service from the container instead of injecting it, so that you can make your service really `public: false` later.

Comment: Nice. Exactly what I looked for.
I tried decorating the container itself and throw a deprecation notice.
This one is way better.

Is it inententional? Didn't find any docs for this one.

Comment: That's internal to symfony core, introduced in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/24104. Btw, please consider upvoting useful answers :)